# Is there a way to mask specific value in the data?

Tags: r

[image]

The image above is the sample data of the dataset I am currently working on, I would like to find a way to mask a specific value (year and month) of the column 'date', so I can use only last two digits (day portion of the date).

Every help is appreciated!!

Comment: Your questioin is not clear.  Do you want to extract the day from the date.  Then you need `df1$date <- format(as.Date(df1$date, '%d'))`

Comment: `lubridate::day(date)` will also pick up day values.

Comment: You got what I meant, sorry for the confusion. I tried your line of code but the output gives 2021-06-20 for all rows. I tried `data$dateday = format(as.Date(data$dateday)` to create a new column that contains the days only.

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang It worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Your code is not creating the same I showed,  `format(as.Date(data$dateday), '%d')`

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R`

```
data$day <- format(as.Date(data$date), '%d')
```